# Type specialization for type list doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I'm doing some template magic to export to current namespace some traits class specialization, that must be implemented only for specific type list. In my first compile time test example for `MakePointerToConst` functor and type list `TypeList<int, void, double, char *>` `static_assert` for listed types compiles as expected and `static_assert` for type `float` shows that there is no specialization for `PointerToConstTrait` for this type.

In other hand, test example for `CustomFunctionPointer` and type list `TypeList<int, double, long int, char, char const *, char[]>` `static_assert` for `float` (which also is not in type list) shows that specialization for `MakeCustomFunctionPointer` exist, but it should not.

As a result, I've got compiler error
 `error: static assertion failed`

```
#pragma once

#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {

template<typename... Args>
struct TypeList {};

template<typename T, typename TypeList>
struct IsTypeInList;

template<typename T, typename U>
struct IsTypeInList<T, TypeList<U>> : public std::bool_constant<std::is_same<T, U>::value> {};

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
struct IsTypeInList<T, TypeList<U, Args...>>
    : public std::bool_constant<std::is_same<T, U>::value
                                || IsTypeInList<T, TypeList<Args...>>::value> {};

namespace compile_time_tests {

static_assert(IsTypeInList<int, TypeList<int>>::value, "");
static_assert(IsTypeInList<int, TypeList<double, int>>::value, "");
static_assert(!IsTypeInList<int, TypeList<double>>::value, "");
static_assert(!IsTypeInList<float, TypeList<double, int>>::value, "");

}  // namespace compile_time_tests

template<typename U, template<typename> class Functor>
struct Apply {
    using Type = typename Functor<U>::Type;
};

template<typename TypeList, template<typename> class Functor>
struct ForEach;

template<template<typename> class Functor, typename FirstTypeOfList>
struct ForEach<TypeList<FirstTypeOfList>, Functor> : public Apply<FirstTypeOfList, Functor> {};

template<template<typename> class Functor, typename FirstTypeOfList, typename... Args>
struct ForEach<TypeList<FirstTypeOfList, Args...>, Functor>
    : public ForEach<TypeList<FirstTypeOfList>, Functor>,
      public ForEach<TypeList<Args...>, Functor> {};

template<typename T>
struct Identity {
    using Type = T;
};

template<template<typename> class Functor>
struct ExportTypeToNamespace {
    template<typename T>
    struct ExportTypeAsFriendToNamespaceFunctor {
        friend struct Identity<typename Functor<T>::Type>;
    };
};

template<typename TypeList, template<typename> class Functor>
struct ExportTraitsListToNamespace {
    template<typename T>
    using ExportTypeAsFriendToNamespaceFunctor =
        typename ExportTypeToNamespace<Functor>::ExportTypeAsFriendToNamespaceFunctor;
    using ExportTraits = ForEach<TypeList, ExportTypeAsFriendToNamespaceFunctor>;
};

template<typename T>
struct MakePointerToConst {
    using Type = T const *;
};

using AvailableTypesForConstPointer = TypeList<int, void, double, char *>;

using DefineMakePointerToConst =
    ExportTraitsListToNamespace<AvailableTypesForConstPointer, MakePointerToConst>;

template<typename T, template<typename> class Functor>
struct RenameTypeToScalar {
    using ScalarType = typename Apply<T, Functor>::Type;
};

template<typename T>
using PointerToConstTrait = RenameTypeToScalar<T, MakePointerToConst>;

namespace compile_time_tests {

static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename PointerToConstTrait<int>::ScalarType, int const *>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename PointerToConstTrait<void>::ScalarType, void const *>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename PointerToConstTrait<double>::ScalarType, double const *>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename PointerToConstTrait<char *>::ScalarType, char * const *>, "");
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<typename PointerToConstTrait<float>::ScalarType, float *>, "");

}
template<typename T>
struct MakeCustomFunctionPointer {
    using Type = T (*)(T const &);
};

using AvailableTypesForCustomFunctionPointer =
    TypeList<int, double, long int, char, char const *, char[]>;

using DefineMakeCustomFunctionPointer =
    ExportTraitsListToNamespace<AvailableTypesForCustomFunctionPointer, MakeCustomFunctionPointer>;

template<typename T, template<typename> class Functor>
struct RenameTypeToFuncPtr {
    using FuncPtr = typename Apply<T, Functor>::Type;
};

template<typename T>
using CustomFunctionPointerTrait = RenameTypeToFuncPtr<T, MakeCustomFunctionPointer>;

// specialization for c-style array just as an example
template<typename T>
struct MakeCustomFunctionPointer<T[]> {
    using Type = T const (&(*)(T const (&)[]))[];
};

namespace compile_time_tests {

static_assert(!std::is_same_v<char const[], char const *>, "");

static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<int>::FuncPtr, int (*)(int const &)>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<double>::FuncPtr,
                             double (*)(double const &)>,
              "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<long int>::FuncPtr,
                             long int (*)(long int const &)>,
              "");
static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<char>::FuncPtr, char (*)(char const &)>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<char const *>::FuncPtr,
                             char const * (*)(char const * const &)>,
              "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<char[]>::FuncPtr,
                             char const (&(*)(char const (&)[]))[]>,
              "");
// Here is compiler error
static_assert(
    !std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<float>::FuncPtr, float (*)(float const &)>,
    "");

}  // namespace compile_time_tests

}  // namespace detail
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the significance of `AvailableTypesForCustomFunctionPointer`. Nothing that goes into `CustomFunctionPointerTrait<float>` depends in any way on any of the `Export*` stuff, as far as I can tell. What type do you expect `CustomFunctionPointerTrait<float>::FuncPtr` to produce, if not `float (*)(float const &)`?

Comment: In fact, everything related to `TypeList`, `ForEach`, `Identity` [can be removed](https://godbolt.org/z/hGW95fTE6) without changing the outcome. I don't understand how those removed parts were supposed to affect anything - the implementation of `PointerToConstTrait` or `CustomFunctionPointerTrait` doesn't depend on those parts in any way.

Comment: If you are asking why `typename PointerToConstTrait<float>::ScalarType` is not `float*`, that's because you forgot `const`. It's `float const *`. Here, too, `AvailableTypesForConstPointer` doesn't have any effect, nor is it clear by what mechanism you hoped it would have any effect.

Comment: *`TypeList<int, double, long int, char, char const *, char[]>`* -- how many of these types can you remove from the list without removing the error? The simpler your test case, the easier it is to spot a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Igor Tandetnik comments, I found a solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace traits::base {

template<typename... Args>
struct TypeList {};

template<typename T, typename TypeList>
struct IsTypeInList;

template<typename T, typename TypeList>
inline constexpr bool IsTypeInListV = IsTypeInList<T, TypeList>::value;

template<typename T, typename SingleType>
struct IsTypeInList<T, TypeList<SingleType>> : public std::is_same<T, SingleType> {};

template<typename T, typename FirstType, typename... RestTypes>
struct IsTypeInList<T, TypeList<FirstType, RestTypes...>>
    : public std::bool_constant<
          std::is_same_v<T, FirstType> || IsTypeInListV<T, TypeList<RestTypes...>>> {};

}  // namespace traits::base

// tests:

namespace testing {
namespace compile_time::test_is_type_in_list {

using namespace traits::base;

static_assert(IsTypeInListV<int, TypeList<int>>, "");
static_assert(IsTypeInListV<int, TypeList<double, int>>, "");
static_assert(!IsTypeInListV<int, TypeList<double>>, "");
static_assert(!IsTypeInListV<float, TypeList<double, int>>, "");

}  // namespace compile_time::test_is_type_in_list

namespace compile_time::test_traits1 {
namespace detail {

template<typename T>
struct MakePointerToConst {
    using Ptr = T const *;
};

template<typename T, bool>
struct PointerToConstTraitImpl;

template<typename T>
struct PointerToConstTraitImpl<T, false>;

template<typename T>
struct PointerToConstTraitImpl<T, true> : public MakePointerToConst<T> {};

}  // namespace detail

using AvailableTypesForConstPointer = traits::base::TypeList<int, void, double, char *>;

template<typename T>
using PointerToConstTrait = detail::PointerToConstTraitImpl<
    T, traits::base::IsTypeInListV<T, AvailableTypesForConstPointer>>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename PointerToConstTrait<int>::Ptr, int const *>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename PointerToConstTrait<void>::Ptr, void const *>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename PointerToConstTrait<double>::Ptr, double const *>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename PointerToConstTrait<char *>::Ptr, char * const *>, "");

}  // namespace compile_time::test_traits1

namespace compile_time::test_traits2 {

template<typename T>
struct MakeCustomFunctionPointer {
    using Type = T (*)(T const &);
};

// alternative specialization for c-style array
template<typename T>
struct MakeCustomFunctionPointer<T[]> {
    using Type = T const (&(*)(T const (&)[]))[];
};

namespace detail {

template<typename T>
struct RenameTypeToFuncPtr {
    using FuncPtr = typename T::Type;
};

template<typename T, bool>
struct CustomFunctionPointerTraitImpl;

template<typename T>
struct CustomFunctionPointerTraitImpl<T, false>;

template<typename T>
struct CustomFunctionPointerTraitImpl<T, true>
    : public RenameTypeToFuncPtr<MakeCustomFunctionPointer<T>> {};

}  // namespace detail

using AvailableTypesForCustomFunctionPointer =
    traits::base::TypeList<int, double, long int, char, char const *, char[]>;

template<typename T>
using CustomFunctionPointerTrait = detail::CustomFunctionPointerTraitImpl<
    T, traits::base::IsTypeInListV<T, AvailableTypesForCustomFunctionPointer>>;

static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<int>::FuncPtr, int (*)(int const &)>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<double>::FuncPtr,
                             double (*)(double const &)>,
              "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<long int>::FuncPtr,
                             long int (*)(long int const &)>,
              "");
static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<char>::FuncPtr, char (*)(char const &)>, "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<char const *>::FuncPtr,
                             char const * (*)(char const * const &)>,
              "");
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename CustomFunctionPointerTrait<char[]>::FuncPtr,
                             char const (&(*)(char const (&)[]))[]>,
              "");

}  // namespace compile_time::test_traits2

}  // namespace testing


int main(int, char**) {
    return 0;
}
```

Now, specialization from type not in list leads to compile time error